# "Recursive value needs type" with case class unapply

Tags: scala

I'm getting `recursive value foo needs type` for the following code:

```
object Repro {
    private final case class Foo(bar: Boolean = false)

    def repro = {
        val foo = Foo(bar = true)
        val Foo(bar) = foo
    }
}
```

However, renaming the unapplied field compiles just fine.

```
object Repro {
    private final case class Foo(bar: Boolean = false)

    def repro = {
        val foo = Foo(bar = true)
        val Foo(bar1) = foo       // <- Here
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing this - using `bar` in the unapply can't possibly reference the name of the field in `Foo`...

Comment: When I compile your program, there is a warning `warning: failed to determine if 'bar = ...' is a named argument or an assignment expression.
an explicit type is required for the definition mentioned in the error message above.`. When you're defined your `Foo` case class, you're already give a default value to `bar` so if you change `val foo = Foo(bar = true)` by `val foo = Foo(true)` there is no error at the compile time. Oh maybe it's a feature (see https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1928).

Comment: Thank you, that's quite helpful. However, why would this cause the issue mentioned in the OP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure what's causing this - using bar in the unapply can't possibly reference the name of the field in Foo...

It's the other way around: the compiler thinks `Foo(bar = true)` refers to the `bar` defined in the next line (because in Scala, [the scope of a name introduced by a declaration or definition is the whole statement sequence containing the binding](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html)). That's why it says "recursive value `foo`": `foo` uses `bar` and `bar` uses `foo`.

It wouldn't type-check if you specify the types for `foo` and `bar`, and if it did you'd get a forward reference error, but the compiler stops before getting there.

Answer (score 0):

hum,I don't have enough reputation to add a comment .SO I post my idea here:

bar in the first line is the private param for its expression.So you change it to bar1 ,error fixed.

Im not very clear about what's the propose of the second line `val Foo(bar)=foo`

If i do not shot the point, i'll delete my answer.

Comment: You may want to read a bit about unapply and how to use it - it's really great. Also, no need to delete your answer. :)

Comment: hum, kinds of embarrasment. Thanks for your raise , still a newer in  scala. Keep learning ~